# I'm searching for original (modern) Browser-Tab Drag&Drop Code for .js

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using this Script (link below) for making multiple tab-rows in Firefox (116.0b6 at the moment). But the problem for me is, it uses an older drag&drop "animation". Not the actual one, where you can actually see the tab dragin around (on the github page there are 2 pictures where both shows the "old" drag&drop animation. Link below).

So because im very noob in js (or actually i have no clue about it), i wanted to ask here, if someone maybe can tell me, what code i have to use, to get the actual, original firefox "tab-dragin animation".

I think, this is the part from the script above, where the drag&drop is defined. But as i said, i have no clue, what i have to change to make it look like in the original.

Part of the Script-code:

`// drag & drop & DropIndicator

```
gBrowser.tabContainer.on_dragover = function(event) {
  var effects = this.getDropEffectForTabDrag(event);

  var ind = this._tabDropIndicator;
  if (effects == "" || effects == "none") {
    ind.hidden = true;
    return;
  }
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  var arrowScrollbox = this.arrowScrollbox;

  if (effects == "link") {
    let tab = this._getDragTargetTab(event, { ignoreTabSides: true });
    if (tab) {
      if (!this._dragTime) {
        this._dragTime = Date.now();
      }
      if (Date.now() >= this._dragTime + this._dragOverDelay) {
        this.selectedItem = tab;
      }
      ind.hidden = true;
      return;
    }
  }

  var rect = arrowScrollbox.getBoundingClientRect();
  var newMarginX, newMarginY;
  let newIndex = this._getDropIndex(event);
  let children = this.allTabs;
  if (newIndex == children.length) {
    let tabRect = this._getVisibleTabs().at(-1).getBoundingClientRect();
    if (RTL_UI) {
      newMarginX = rect.right - tabRect.left;
    } else {
      newMarginX = tabRect.right - rect.left;
    }
      newMarginY = tabRect.top - rect.top + tabRect.height / 2 - rect.height / 2;
  } else {
    let tabRect = children[newIndex].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (RTL_UI) {
      newMarginX = rect.right - tabRect.right;
    } else {
      newMarginX = tabRect.left - rect.left;
    }
      newMarginY = tabRect.top - rect.top + tabRect.height / 2 - rect.height / 2;
  }

  ind.hidden = false;
  newMarginX += ind.clientWidth / 2;
  if (RTL_UI) {
    newMarginX *= -1;
  }
  ind.style.transform = "translate(" + Math.round(newMarginX) + "px," + Math.round(newMarginY) + "px)";
}

gBrowser.tabContainer.on_drop = function(event) {
  var dt = event.dataTransfer;
  var dropEffect = dt.dropEffect;
  var draggedTab;
  let movingTabs;
  if (dt.mozTypesAt(0)[0] == TAB_DROP_TYPE) {
    // tab copy or move
    draggedTab = dt.mozGetDataAt(TAB_DROP_TYPE, 0);
    // not our drop then
    if (!draggedTab) {
      return;
    }
    movingTabs = draggedTab._dragData.movingTabs;
    draggedTab.container._finishGroupSelectedTabs(draggedTab);
  }

  this._tabDropIndicator.hidden = true;
  event.stopPropagation();
  if (draggedTab && dropEffect == "copy") {
    // copy the dropped tab (wherever it's from)
    let newIndex = this._getDropIndex(event);
    let draggedTabCopy;
    for (let tab of movingTabs) {
      let newTab = gBrowser.duplicateTab(tab);
      gBrowser.moveTabTo(newTab, newIndex++);
      if (tab == draggedTab) {
        draggedTabCopy = newTab;
      }
    }
    if (draggedTab.container != this || event.shiftKey) {
      this.selectedItem = draggedTabCopy;
    }
  } else if (draggedTab && draggedTab.container == this) {
    let oldTranslateX = Math.round(draggedTab._dragData.translateX);
    let tabWidth = Math.round(draggedTab._dragData.tabWidth);
    let translateOffset = oldTranslateX % tabWidth;
    let newTranslateX = oldTranslateX - translateOffset;
    if (oldTranslateX > 0 && translateOffset > tabWidth / 2) {
      newTranslateX += tabWidth;
    } else if (oldTranslateX < 0 && -translateOffset > tabWidth / 2) {
      newTranslateX -= tabWidth;
    }

    let dropIndex;
    if (draggedTab._dragData.fromTabList) {
      dropIndex = this._getDropIndex(event);
    } else {
      dropIndex = this._getDropIndex(event);
     // "animDropIndex" in draggedTab._dragData &&
     // draggedTab._dragData.animDropIndex;
    }
    let incrementDropIndex = true;
    if (dropIndex && dropIndex > movingTabs[0]._tPos) {
      dropIndex--;
      incrementDropIndex = false;
    }

    if (oldTranslateX && oldTranslateX != newTranslateX && !gReduceMotion) {
      for (let tab of movingTabs) {
        tab.setAttribute("tabdrop-samewindow", "true");
        tab.style.transform = "translateX(" + newTranslateX + "px)";
        let postTransitionCleanup = () => {
          tab.removeAttribute("tabdrop-samewindow");

          this._finishAnimateTabMove();
          if (dropIndex !== false) {
            gBrowser.moveTabTo(tab, dropIndex);
            if (incrementDropIndex) {
              dropIndex++;
            }
          }

          gBrowser.syncThrobberAnimations(tab);
        };
        if (gReduceMotion) {
          postTransitionCleanup();
        } else {
          let onTransitionEnd = transitionendEvent => {
            if (
              transitionendEvent.propertyName != "transform" ||
              transitionendEvent.originalTarget != tab
            ) {
              return;
            }
            tab.removeEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionEnd);

            postTransitionCleanup();
          };
          tab.addEventListener("transitionend", onTransitionEnd);
        }
      }
    } else {
      this._finishAnimateTabMove();
      if (dropIndex !== false) {
        for (let tab of movingTabs) {
          gBrowser.moveTabTo(tab, dropIndex);
          if (incrementDropIndex) {
            dropIndex++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (draggedTab) {
    // Move the tabs. To avoid multiple tab-switches in the original window,
    // the selected tab should be adopted last.
    const dropIndex = this._getDropIndex(event);
    let newIndex = dropIndex;
    let selectedTab;
    let indexForSelectedTab;
    for (let i = 0; i < movingTabs.length; ++i) {
      const tab = movingTabs[i];
      if (tab.selected) {
        selectedTab = tab;
        indexForSelectedTab = newIndex;
      } else {
        const newTab = gBrowser.adoptTab(tab, newIndex, tab == draggedTab);
        if (newTab) {
          ++newIndex;
        }
      }
    }
    if (selectedTab) {
      const newTab = gBrowser.adoptTab(
        selectedTab,
        indexForSelectedTab,
        selectedTab == draggedTab
      );
      if (newTab) {
        ++newIndex;
      }
    }`
```

Github-Link: https://github.com/Endor8/userChrome.js/tree/master/Multirowtabs/Firefox-114

Yeah, as i said i have sadly no clue, what i should change, so im hoping you could help me.

For sure i tried to google and i also asked in a forum, which has made a similair script, but he could not help me.